# Sequential compactness of $S_\Omega$ and unbounded sequences.

Tags: general-topology, ordinals, well-orders

I'm currently trying to prove that

> The space $S_\Omega$ is sequentially compact.

where $S_\Omega$ is the first uncountable ordinal (i.e. it is well ordered, uncountable and all proper sections are countable).

So far, I've managed to see the following

1. By an argument similar to the one done in the reals, sequences in $S_\Omega$ have monotone subsequences: we can say that a point of a sequence is a 'viewpoint' if it is greater than all posterior terms. If there are infinitely many viewpoints, we can construct a decreasing sequence. If on the contrary there are only finitely many, this implies that at a certain point, every term is eventually preceded by a greater one, thus allowing the construction of an increasing sequence.
2. If a sequence is decreasing, it converges in $S_\Omega$. In effect, it will converge to $\min_n x_n$.

In the same fashion, if a sequence is increasing and the set $S = \{x : x \geq x_n \ (\forall n)\}$ is non empty, its first element $s$ will be the sequence's limit point. However, it may *a priori* be that the original sequence is unbounded. My intuition is that this cannot occur precisely because such a scenario in itself would contradict the sequential compactness of $S_\Omega$, which I'm trying to prove. So, any ideas on how to prove, if true, that no sequence is $S_\Omega$ is unbounded?

Edit: as Henno Brandsma has referenced, theorem 10.3 of Munkres proves that $S$ is non empty, thus the sequence has a supremum (to which it converges): sections of each term $S_{x_n}$ are countable so by cardinality,

$$
S_{\Omega}  \setminus \bigcup_{n \geq 1}S_{x_n} \neq \emptyset.
$$

Comment: A countable union of countable ordinals is a countable ordinal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof idea can be made to work: Let $(x_n)$ be any sequence in $S_\Omega$.

In any linearly ordered set we have a subsequence determined by indices $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \ldots$, such that either

1. $\forall k: x_{n_k} \le x_{n_{k+1}}$ or
2. $\forall k: x_{n_k} \ge x_{n_{k+1}}$.

In the latter case we cannot have the sequence be *strictly* decreasing because $S_\Omega$ is well-ordered and the sequence stabilises at some $x$ such that all terms beyond a finite initial segment are equal to $x$. This clearly defines a (constant thus convergent) subsequence.

In the former case $C= \sup\{x_{n_k}: k=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ exists and lies in $S_\Omega$ (thm 10.3 Munkres (2nd ed.)) and by the definition of the order topology one can check that this subsequence converges to $C$.

Comment: As a aside, the motonone subsequence result is a nice consequence of the general Ramsey theorem for finite colourings of infinite graphs.

Comment: Using that we can even have 3 cases, constant ($=$  everywhere), strictly increasing and strictly decreasing $<,>$ instead of $\le,\ge$. The constant case is trivial, and the strictly decreasing case impossible by well-order. Saves a bit of reasoning for the decreasing case.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\Omega$ then let $C = \sup \{x_n: n \in \omega\}$. This is a countable ordinal. $C+1$ is a compact countable subspace in which $(x_n)$ "lives" and $C+1$ is first countable, hence second countable hence metrisable. So $C+1$ is sequentially compact and hence there is a convergent subsequence of the original sequence converging in $C+1$ and thus also in $\Omega$.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ordinals, other than with the definition of  $S_\Omega$. I do see that $C$ either is in $S_\Omega$ or in $S_\Omega \cup \{\Omega\}$, but I'm not seeing why the latter cannot happen. I mean, the sequence embedded in $S_\Omega \cup \{\Omega\}$ may be convergent but not in $S_\Omega$, no? So we would need from $C$ to be in $S_\Omega$ itself. Also, I don't immediately see how $C+1$ is compact nor am I too familiar with first/second countable spaces. Are these properties unavoidable to prove the result? I apologize if this sounds nonsensical.

Comment: @GuidoA. It's theorem 10.3 in Munkres (2nd ed) that says that the sup is in $S_\Omega$.

Comment: @GuidoA. compactness follows as every subset of a countable ordinal that has a maximum, has a max and a min. It's a standard result on compactness in ordered spaces. And we only need first countability (a local countable base at each point, which is obvious in any countable ordered space) for the equivalence of compact and sequentially compact.

Comment: Ok, great. I'll come back to this in a bit, and accept the answer accordingly. Thank you for your time and insight, as usual.

Comment: @GuidoA. Glad to help. Maybe others will post more elementary proofs. ..

Answer (score 0):

Take any sequence $\{x_i\in \omega_1:i\in \omega\}$ in $\omega_1$. Since every sequence is countable and any countable subset of $\omega_1$, which is first uncountable ordinal, has an upper bound then every sequence has an upper bound in $\omega_1$. So $\{\alpha \in \omega_1: \alpha\geq x_i, i\in \omega\}\neq \emptyset $. Then it has minimum $\alpha_0$. If the minimum in the sequence we can take constant sequence which consists of the minimum as a converges subsequence. Now assume the minimum is not in the sequence. So every $x_i<\alpha_0$ then there must be some non-decreasing $x_{k_i}$'s such that $\alpha_0 > x_{k_i}> x_i$ for every $x_i$ and we can take the $\{x_{k_i}\}$ as a  converges subsequence.